# eCryptFS on Ubuntu Server 14x (problem with ecryptfs-generate-tpm-key)

Tags: server, ecryptfs

I faced a problem that I can't solve by my own. I'm trying to install ecryptfs at an Ubuntu Server that will crypt a folder with thelp of Trusted Processing Module (TPM).
I'm following the following instruction from IBM (it is not for Ubuntu but at least something) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaai/ecrypts/liaaiecryptfsbegin.htm

And I stopped at the phase when I need to generate TPM key with help of eCryptFS-Utils programme. I should use  "ecryptfs-generate-tpm-key -p 0 -p 2 -p 3" command to do this. But there is not such kind of a tool in Ubuntu ecryptfs-utils!

It is in Debian package but not in Ubuntu. I was trying to install Debian package manually but with no success. There are too many dependeces to other libs which are not in Ununtu or they are too old for debian package.

So, what should I do?

Comment: are you sure? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils  and http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/ecryptfs-utils

Comment: I also tried the same procedure under Debian - it works. Still hassle with Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.

Here is the list of the files in the compiled package http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/ecryptfs-utils/filelist
And there is no ecryptfs-generate-tpm-key file in it. Only man reference.

This file presents as a source in the source package. But I couldn't compile it completely - to many dependencies in the compiler that I couldn't force it to work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to tell, this tool is obsolete and apparently isn't built any more with the Ubuntu ecryptfs userspace tools.  As you read in the IBM whitepaper, the `ecryptfs-generate-tpm-key` command is used in conjunction with the TSPI key module of ecryptfs.

But a maintainer of `ecryptfs` has stated that the TSPI module was a proof of concept (supposedly it doesn't perform well since it uses TPM on every file I/O) and should not have made it into the upstream `ecryptfs-utils` project to begin with:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/787907.  He said he was going to remove it when kernel 3.1 was released; I suppose that has probably happened by now.  (Maybe he missed the man page?)

Apparently the replacement is to use trusted and encrypted keys on the kernel keyring, but I'm struggling with that, too: [Practical use of ecryptfs, encrypted keys, and TPM: how to convert existing user key to encrypted key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750792/practical-use-of-ecryptfs-encrypted-keys-and-tpm-how-to-convert-existing-user)