# Practical use of ecryptfs, encrypted keys, and TPM: how to convert existing user key to encrypted key?

Tags: kernel, encryption, ecryptfs, keyrings, tpm

Short version of this question is:  **How do I convert a user key on the kernel keyring
storing ecryptfs authentication token / FEFEK to an encrypted key on keyring?**
(I.e. how to add an encrypted key with user-specified plaintext data, instead
of a randomly-generated key - such as a pre-existing mounting passphrase for
an existing ecryptfs file system.)  Read on for why...

I'm trying to figure out how to practically use ecryptfs with a TPM, and the
information I'm finding is generally out-of-date/obsolete.  All I've found is
blog articles or IBM whitepapers from a few years ago that appear to use
features that don't exist anymore / unmaintained features (the removed TSPI module, and the OpenSSL TPM library that seems unmaintained and is no longer in my package manager).  I've gathered that
the proper way to do this now involves trusted and encrypted kernel keys, as
per:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/keys-ecryptfs.txt
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/keys-trusted-encrypted.txt

The strategy outlined in the above documentation indicates the idea would be to
make a new trusted key, sealed with the TPM, and then use it to make a new
encrypted key in the ecryptfs format, specifying the trusted key as the master.
That's easy enough to follow, and does what I'm looking for, except...

The problem is if the TPM dies, I need to recover my data (e.g. computer dies,
and need to restore from encrypted backups).  What I'm wanting to do is use a
passphrase to decrypt data if the TPM is not available, to be used only in
special circumstances.  Alternatively, users might have a pre-existing
ecryptfs file system with a mounting passphrase / FEFEK already chosen - i.e.
you don't want to re-encrypt all your files just to use the TPM.  This seems
like an obvious need, yet I'm have trouble figuring out the "how".

From the above documentation:

```
The data structure defined by eCryptfs to contain information required for the
FEK decryption is called authentication token and, currently, can be stored in a
kernel key of the 'user' type, inserted in the user's session specific keyring
by the userspace utility 'mount.ecryptfs' shipped with the package
'ecryptfs-utils'.

Encrypted keys of the newly introduced [ecryptfs encrypted] format store an
authentication token in its payload with a FEFEK randomly generated by the
kernel and protected by the parent master key.  [What if I want to use an
existing FEFEK?]
```

OK, so it sounds to me like the kernel is storing the encrypted key in the same
format as a regular user key that would be added to the keyring by the ecryptfs
userspace tools (e.g. by `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` or the mount helper).  That is,
the payload of the user key and the encrypted key are basically one and the
same, except the kernel won't allow userspace to read the encrypted key in
unencrypted format.  Right?

So I think what I want to do is this - am I on the right track here?

1. Use [`ecryptfs-add-passphrase`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/ecryptfs-add-passphrase.1.html) to add a mounting passphrase to the keyring.
   (It could be a mounting passphrase for an existing ecryptfs filesystem).
   Now I have a user key on the keyring storing an ecryptfs authentication
   token.  The mounting passphrase can be complex and stored in an offline
   secure location, perhaps protected by [`ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase.1.html), and only
   used in a data recovery scenario (e.g. if the TPM goes up in smoke).
2. Create a new trusted key in the keyring, as per above kernel documentation.
3. Convert the existing user key storing authentication token from
   `ecrypt-add-passphrase` in step #1 into an encrypted key on the keyring, using
   the trusted key as the master key.  (**This is where I'm stuck.**)
4. Remove the user key from the keyring since we don't need it any more.
5. Use [`keyctl pipe`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/keyctl.1.html) to save the encrypted key to a file on disk for later
   mounting.

Ordinary day-to-day mounting would work like:

1. Load and unseal trusted key into keyring.
2. Load encrypted key blob from step #5 above into encrypted key in keyring,
   using trusted key as master key.
3. Mount using the encrypted key from previous step.

If the TPM is destroyed or lost:

1. Use `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` to add the mounting passphrase from backup into
   an authentication token stored in a user key.
2. Mount using this user key.

**So my key question is this**:  How do I convert a user key storing authentication
token to an encrypted key, as in step #3 in the setup procedure above?  For
example, kernel docs say this to decrypt an existing encrypted key previously exported
with keyctl pipe :

```
keyctl add encrypted name "load hex_blob" ring
```

But I want to do something like this to make a new encrypted key from some
pre-existing plaintext:

```
keyctl add encrypted name "load ecryptfs trusted:masterkey `keyctl print <id of user key holding plaintext authentication token / FEFEK / mounting passphrase>`" @u
```

(This as opposed to the random new key generated with
`add encrypted name "new ecryptfs"`)

If the above isn't possible then what am I missing in my strategy?  Feels like
I'm missing some obvious information here.

Comment: So, you want to store keys in the kernel keyring, and have them encrypted in there? How is that different from the regular "wrapped-passphrase" file?   (Q was tl;dr all the details)

Comment: @Xen2050: So, the regular wrapped-passphrase file holds an encrypted mounting passphrase, protected by the wrapping passphrase.  Normally the mount helper unwraps the mounting passphrase using the wrapping passphrase, and then puts the mounting passphrase in an authentication token in the keyring, using key of type "user".  I want to change that process by doing a one-time setup of directly putting the mounting passphrase in an "encrypted" key in keyring.  Encrypted key payloads can be sealed by TPM, and cannot be read in decrypted form by userspace.

Comment: @Xen2050: "store keys in the kernel keyring, and have them encrypted in there" --- as I understand it, the key is still accessible decrypted in the keyring, but it is encrypted/decrypted with a master key whenever the key transitions to/from userspace.  The master key can be a key of type trusted, which is sealed by the TPM.

Comment: I may not be following too well... but are you trying to protect the key against a malicious root user? Or it's just that the TPM only works with an encrypted kernel key, it won't work with the plain wrapped-passphrase file?

Comment: @Xen2050: Have you read the links to the kernel documentation at the top of my message?  It would hopefully make more sense if you do, although the documentation isn't as clear as I would have liked.